# Jenkins when changeset not evaluating to true

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm testing out checking for changes to various parts of the repo within my Jenkinsfile. I have the following simple code block in my file:

```
stage('When changes to root') {
  when {
    changeset "*/*"
  }
  steps {
    script {
      deployAllApps = true
    }
  }
}
```

My Jenkinsfile actually lives in the root. So I would assume when I make a change to that file and push it should be recognized as a change to a file in the root directory. However, the above always evaluates to false. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty straightforward. Even though all the documentation I read said to do it the way I listed, the initial '*/' characters were the problem. For root I just needed to change `changeset "*/*"` to `changeset "*"`.